# Python text file. Finding strings that contain only characters 'abcdef'

Tags: python, text-files

I need to write a code that shows all the strings containing only 'abcdef'. Then I have add up the hexadecimal number represented by these characters within each word and print the word with the largest value. This is what I have. I'm a beginner programer and I was just trying out things, which haven't worked.

```
def text():
    words = open("words.txt",'r')
    wordstring = words.read()
    wordList = wordstring.split()
    return wordList
def findLetters(wordList):
    letterList = []
    letters = 'abcdef'
    for word in wordList:
        for letter in word:
            if letter in word not in letters:
                break
            else:
                letterList.append(word)
    return letterList


def final():
    book = text()
    fin = findLetters(book)
    print(fin) 
final()
```

Example:

strings 'faded' 'blink' 'bad' 'fair' 'dead'
the code would only recognized those containing 'abcdef' so 'faded' 'bad' and 'dead'. Then using hexadecimal (a=10, b=11, c=12, d=13, e=14, f=15) the code would add up the value for those words. So 'faded' would be (15+10+13+14+13 = 65). 'bad' would be (11+10+13 = 34) and 'dead' would be (13+14+10+13 = 50). It would then determine which one has the largest value, in this case it's 'faded' with a value of 65. So the output would simply be 'faded'.

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: RTFM regular expressions. http://regular-expressions.info, [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start, but let's change your `findLetters` function.

```
def findLetters(wordList):
    letterList = []
    letters = 'abcdef'
    for word in wordList: # good
        for letter in word: # good
            if letter in word not in letters: # nope, looks for True/False in letters
                break
            else:
                letterList.append(word) # nope, appends the word multiple times
    return letterList
```

So let's restructure it as follows.

```
def findLetters(wordlist):
    letterList = []
    letters = 'abcdef'
    for word in wordlist:
        if all(letter in letters for letter in word):
            letterList.append(word)
    return letterList
```

This goes through each word in the list, checking if `all` of its `letter`s are `in` the acceptable `letters`. If they are, it adds the word to the results list. The key difference is that, instead of adding the entire word every time it finds a matching character as your algorithm would've done if it had a correct `if` statement (like simply `if letter in letters:`), it only adds the word after making sure all the characters are a proper match.

We can use a comprehension in this function if we want:

```
def findLetters(wordlist):
    return [word for word in wordlist if all(letter in 'abcdef' for letter in word)]
```

Comment: Thank you! I really like how you answered this, by telling me what was wrong in my code and what was right. Thank you again. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `re` module.

```
import re

def check_alpha(strr):

    try:
        r = re.compile("^[a-f]*$")
        return r.match(strr).group()
    except:
        pass

def get_hex_value(strr):

    hex_dict = {
            'a': 10,
            'b': 11,
            'c': 12,
            'd': 13,
            'e': 14,
            'f': 15
    }

    return sum([hex_dict[s] for s in strr])


blah = ['faded', 'blink', 'bad', 'fair', 'dead']

# Get all the matches.
matches = [x for x in map(check_alpha, blah) if x is not None]

# Get the maximum value.
max_value = max([get_hex_value(m) for m in matches])

# Get all the words whose hex value matches the max value,
# because you never know when you have more than one match.
max_value = [x for x in matches if get_hex_value(x) == max_value]

print max_value
```

Result:

```
['faded']
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Very explicit code and can definitely be improved, but I encourage you to study it since you're a beginner. Pay special attention to the syntax of list comprehensions so you don't have to write loops one too many times.